# Angular Wrapper method read from api

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

This is my service method before wrapper

```
getMenusByUserId(userId: string): Observable<MenuData[]> {
        var request = { userId: userId };

        var result= this.httpClient.post<MenuData[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/Menu/GetMenusByUserId', request);
        return result;
    }
```

It is working fine .  Now Data coming from api wrapped from another class

```
  export interface Result<T> {
    succeeded: boolean;
    message: string;
    errors: ErrorMessage;  
    data: T;
}

export interface ErrorMessage
{
    key:string;
    message:string;
}
```

All the list of menu coming in **`data`** of result interface.
So i changed my service class to below  and error showing like

[image: Update scrren shot]

Edit:

```
getMenusByUserId(userId: string): Observable<Result<MenuData[]>> {
        var request = { userId: userId };

        var result= this.httpClient.post<MenuData[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/Menu/GetMenusByUserId', request);
        return result.data;
    }
```

How to read all menus and same needs to written to component. Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried returning `Observable<Result<MenuData>>` from `getMenusByUserId` ?

Comment: am new to angular ..but i tried same ..but vs code showing error like scren shot..Code updated in the question

Comment: No I mean `MenuData[]` without `[]`, because they're already included in `data: T[];`. You should also do the same for the post line : `this.httpClient.post<Result<MenuData>>`.

Comment: thanks ..But its my mistake. now updated the interdace...showing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpClient return observable so you need to subscribe it and with help of pipe you modify data stream with help of rxjs operators so result is returning observable

```
getMenusByUserId(userId: string): Observable<Result<MenuData[]>> {
    var request = { userId: userId };

    var result= this.httpClient.post(environment.apiUrl + '/Menu/GetMenusByUserId', request).pipe(map( res => Result<res>));
        return result;
    }
```

in component from where you call this service method

```
this.menuDataService.getMenusByUserId(userId).subscribe(resp => {
    console.log('your required response : ', resp)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an observable. Observalbe doesnt have .data property.

Observable's emitted value has .data.

```
observable.subscribe(x => {
this.idontknow = x.data
});
```

Or if its an Array, then the element of the array has .data

And change httpClient's post request type to post<Result<MenuData[]>>